# Custom Tab Content

Tags: android

I made custom tabs using this tutorial: http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

I have them completely customized and looking nice, but now I don't know how to add content to the tabs. I don't even know where to start with the way this code is written, any help? Thanks.

This is the code that I think sets the content:

```
private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);

    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;}
    });
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);

}
```

I don't know what this is doing with "TabContentFactory"

Comment: I tried the same blog and was facing the same issue but I solved it myself then. I will post the answer soon, wait a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too followed the same blog and was facing problem, while adding the Intent's. So, finally I fixed it myself. What I did is,

1.) `public class CustomTabActivity extends Activity` here I changed it to `extend TabActivity`

2.) Just add the content using Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Hello.class);
        TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(intent);
```

That's it and it worked. Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the [tutorial given on the android website](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). Combined with the tutorial you used, it should give you completely what you want.

Specifically, to add content to to each tab you add and activity to each tab like so:

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: I can't figure it out, the way that tutorial is set up is confusing me. I don't see where the tabs are getting their content from.

Comment: I'm getting force close when using this method in this tutorial. I edited my question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
private void addActivityTab(int labelResId, int iconResId, Intent intent) {
    String tabLabel = getString(labelResId);        
    View indicator = View.inflate(this, R.layout.simple_tab_spec, null);        
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) indicator.findViewById(R.id.simple_tab_spec_icon);
    icon.setImageResource(iconResId);       
    TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tabLabel).setIndicator(indicator).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec); }
```

The first argument is the title of your tab item, the second argument is the background image of your tab item.
You should create an intent object to set the parameters and the target activity.